# Embedding blog content in a webpage

Tags: html, iframe, blogs, blogger

I am working on a relatively simple website and I am required to incorporate some form of news feed into it, that can be easily updated without having to re-upload the site each time.

My solution to this currently is to use an `<iframe>` that displays content from a Google Blogger blog. However, the fact the iframe is smaller than the width of the blog I am asking it to display, makes the whole thing look very messy and unprofessional.

I have tried to remove the majority of the formatting from my blog, so it looks better in the iframe, however this also means the blog has no formatting when viewed fullscreen, or on the blogger site itself.

My question is:
I am wondering if I can manually retrieve the blog posts feed from blogger's database, and display them with my own formatting on my webpage, leaving the actual blog page untouched?

I hope I have explained that well enough, please comment if you require clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, from my point of reference your problem is more of customising your blog. Well you can try this.
[**blogger**](http://www.blogger.com)-->**Template**-->**Edit HTML**(Instead of customisation)

There you will get messy HTML code. Find **CSS Strips** and edit as you want them. You can change variety from there. Gracius

Comment: thanks. its just blogger has so many css tags its very confusing to establish which is which. i have a workaround now anyway.